# javascript access array from another class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i want to access an array from another class
**FirstClass.ts**

```
items:any = [];

export class ContainsDataArray {

  saveItems(item){
    this.items.push(item); 
 }
}
```

**SecondClass**

```
export class AccessArrayfromAnotherClass {
(Call the array from the FirstClass this.items to be exact)

}
```

Comment: Just return the array from `getData()`

Comment: Ok how can i call it in the secondClass I'm still learning thank you so much

Comment: Have you instantiated your first class anywhere? Please post your code

Comment: Where does `somearray` come from? Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: somearray coming from json data i pushed it to this.items and im trying to call this.items from another class

Comment: im gonna edit the code so you can see exactly what i have

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
class A {
    static array: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
    constructor() {}
}

class B {
    constructor() {}
    
    getArray() {
     console.log(A.array);
    }
}

f = new B();
f.getArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Object-Oriented Programming (OOP), you can use **composition** or **inheritance**.

### Composition

```js
class ContainsDataArray {
  constructor() {
    this._items = [];
  }
  
  saveItem(item) {
    this._items.push(item); 
  }
  
  get items() {
    return this._items;
  }
}

class AccessArrayfromAnotherClass {
  constructor() {
    this._ref = new ContainsDataArray();
  }
  
  get ref() {
    return this._ref;
  }
}

let instance = new AccessArrayfromAnotherClass();

instance.ref.saveItem('Foo');
instance.ref.saveItem('Bar');

console.log(instance.ref.items);
```

### Inheritance

```js
class ContainsDataArray {
  constructor() {
    this._items = [];
  }
  
  saveItem(item) {
    this._items.push(item); 
  }
  
  get items() {
    return this._items;
  }
}

class AccessArrayfromAnotherClass extends ContainsDataArray {}

let instance = new AccessArrayfromAnotherClass();

instance.saveItem('Foo');
instance.saveItem('Bar');

console.log(instance.items);
```